# Not able to retrieve information about db instances from the describe_instance method using boto.rds2

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, rds

```
import boto.rds2
conn = boto.rds2.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
def status(conn):
    response = conn.describe_db_instances()
    instances=responses['DescribeDBInstancesResponse'] ['DescribeDBInstancesResult'] 
['DBInstances']

print(instances['Engine'])
```

I want to get information about rds instances using the following code . why am i not able to get it Engine= mysql/sqlserver?. I am getting a list of dictionaries to the response variable. i want the output to be stored in a dictionary or list  so that i can easily access those variables later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```
def status(conn):
    status_map = {}
    response = conn.describe_db_instances()
    instances = response['DescribeDBInstancesResponse']['DescribeDBInstancesResult']['DBInstances']
    for instance in instances:
        status_map[instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']] = instance['Engine']
    return status_map
```

Comment: @garnaat- How about storing these values in some dictionary or list so that we can retrieve the information at a later stage?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean but I have modified the example a bit. Perhaps that is closer to what you want.